# Moving SQL Data to temp table before doing an inner join

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT  MAX(CP2.CounterpartyKey) 
FROM    GFRM_STAR2.SDS.Counterparty CP2
WHERE   CP1.Id = CP2.Id
        AND ISNULL(CP2.EffectiveFromDate, '1900-01-01') <= CONVERT(DATE, '20170620', 112)
```

This is a sub query inside another SQL query, but the rest isn't changing so I have omitted it for this question

What I'm trying to do is change this is move the data I get from CP2.CounterpartyKey into a temp table then do an inner join instead of what I'm doing now.

To begin with I've amended the query to be

```
   SELECT  MAX(CP2.CounterpartyKey) 
   INTO    #Temp
   FROM    GFRM_STAR2.SDS.Counterparty CP2
   WHERE   CP1.Id = CP2.Id
           AND ISNULL(CP2.EffectiveFromDate, '1900-01-01') <= CONVERT(DATE, '20170620', 112)
```

But when I run, I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'

I'm new to SQL and I'm unsure why this is failing as looking around, my syntax looks to correct, but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Try giving your MAX() column an alias.

Comment: You should also tell us what version of SQL you are using (though it may be obvious to someone who knows this flavor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias Column name , because temp table needs a column name where you will be inserting into

```
SELECT  MAX(CP2.CounterpartyKey)  as CounterPartKey
       into     #Temp
       FROM    GFRM_STAR2.SDS.Counterparty CP2
       WHERE   CP1.Id = CP2.Id
               AND ISNULL(CP2.EffectiveFromDate, '1900-01-01') <= CONVERT(DATE, '20170620', 112)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT  MAX(CP2.CounterpartyKey)   
FROM    GFRM_STAR2.SDS.Counterparty CP2
WHERE   CP1.Id = CP2.Id
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Before this Query you should have a command to

```
 create table #Temp (CounterPartyMax int)
```

and after you are done be sure to delete with

```
drop table #Temp
```